# The provided edit sequence "" is out-of-date

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I update customer that exist in cloud in Quickbooks destop 2013; 
I use API v3 to insert a invoice that use the customer after run intuit sync manager,i find a error:
 "Operation failed with errors: \nInvalid field value CustomerRef: Invalid Customer ID: [NG:1002560062]";
I find the customer object in errored state then use the V2 status(deprecated) API to get detail:
 "The provided edit sequence \"1390358620\" is out-of-date. "

How to solve this question?

Thanks.

Comment: I had this issue due to closing and reopening the connection to Quickbooks between operations.

Answer (score 3):

This generally indicates that someone updated your object in the QuickBooks GUI, or from another integrated application, immediately before your application tried to update it.

### For QuickBooks desktop/for Windows

To fix this, you should query for the object, get the latest `EditSequence` value, and re-submit the update request with the latest value.

### For QuickBooks Online

QuickBooks Online has the same concept, but they call it a `SyncToken` instead of an `EditSequence`.

To fix this, you should query for the object, get the latest `SyncToken` value for the object, and re-submit the update request.

This clears the error code and should cause the object to sync.

Comment: Do you have any idea about this error in QBD? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75510047/editing-multiple-times-of-so-gives-error-qbwc-error-3200-the-provided-edit-se?noredirect=1&lq=1)